# How to Run job on Jenkins with Selenium Server

Tags: selenium, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, selenium-ide

I launched my tests IDE from Jenkins and the job failed.In the console output,I detected this information: "Unable to access jarfile C:\dev\selenium\standalone\selenium-server.jar".

I verified that the jar is executable by everyone...

---

I launched this commande  :

```
``java -jar selenium-server.jar -trustAllSSLCertificates -userExtensions "ftp://selenium:Y3ey6KnDg4D3@zei335a1:721/js/user-extensions.js" -htmlsuite "*firefox" https://zed330z7:59443/stm_ihm/ "ftp://selenium:Y3ey6KnDg4D3@zei335a1:721/tests_suites/Total_Courbes.htm" "ftp://selenium:Y3ey6KnDg4D3@zei335a1:721/rapports/rapport.html"`
```

from Jenkins and I obtain :

```
`Started by user sm14b10n
    [EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
    [EnvInject] - Preparing an environment for the build.
    [EnvInject] - Keeping Jenkins system variables.
    [EnvInject] - Keeping Jenkins build variables.
    [EnvInject] - Injecting contributions.
    Building in workspace /appli/projects/jenkins_atos/jenkins/workspace/STM_V1_V2_TESTS
    [STM_V1_V2_TESTS] $ cmd /c call /var/jenkins/jenkins_atos/tmp/hudson8121199609581456632.bat
    FATAL: command execution failed
    java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmd" (in directory "/appli/projects/jenkins_atos/jenkins/workspace/STM_V1_V2_TESTS"): java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:475)
        at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:244)
        at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:216)
        at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:803)
        at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:381)
        at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:97)
        at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:66)
        at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:770)
        at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:199)
        at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:160)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:533)
        at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1745)
        at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:164)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:81)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:468)
        ... 15 more
    Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
    Publishing Selenium report...
    Missing directory ftp://selenium:Y3ey6KnDg4D3@zei335a1:721/rapports/*.html
    Build step 'Publish Selenium Html Report' marked build as failure
    [BFA] Scanning build for known causes...

    [BFA] Done. 0s
    Started calculate disk usage of build
    Finished Calculation of disk usage of build in 0 seconds
    Started calculate disk usage of workspace
    Finished Calculation of disk usage of workspace in 0 seconds
    Finished: FAILURE`
```

---

Can you give me yours opinions about this problem ?

Thanks in Advance,

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a batch file for Selenium IDE Test Suite. [Tutorial](http://software-testing-tutorials-automation.blogspot.in/2013/07/steps-of-running-selenium-ide-test.html).

   - Download the Selenium Server and start creating the test in IDE.
   - Save the IDE tests at proper location.
   - Create a batch file giving the location of your IDE tests.

     ```
     java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar -htmlSuite "*firefox" "%baseurl%" "%suite%"
     ```
2. Create a Jenkins Job to run the batch file. [Tutorial](http://learn-automation.com/selenium-integration-with-jenkins/)

   - Download and configure the Jenkins on your machine.
   - Create a Jenkins job by adding build step as Execute Windows batch command.
   - Run the Jenkins job to execute the IDE tests.